# copy file from one Linux machine to another in a intranet

Tags: linux, scp

I used the command:

```
scp filename.c user@172.100.102.187:/user/pradeep
```

Here I want to copy file to 172.100.102.187 in /user/pradeep but it gives a
error:

```
scp: /user/pradeep: No such file or directory
```

What is the command to copy a file from one system to another?

Comment: You are using the correct command. Can you confirm that the target location is infact /user/pradeep and not something like /usr/pradeep etc? Also, can you confirm that the user directory does in fact sit at the server root and not your home directory root?

Comment: This is a linux question and why this moved to stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 2):

The command you used is fine.

The problem is that on the machine 172.100.102.187, the directory `/user/pradeep` does not exist.  Are you sure it isn't `/home/pradeep` or some other name?

Assuming you actually do have that directory on that machine, the problem that might be afflicting you could be 'automounted NFS home directory'.  That is, if the home directory is automounted when you login, it could be that `scp` does not trigger that mount operation, and therefore your home directory appears to be missing.  I'm not sure whether this is still a problem - it used to afflict me periodically a decade ago.

Comment: You can simply use `scp.....:~` as the home directory also.

Answer (score 0):

Well your syntax seems good :

```
scp /path/to/local/file user@remote_host:/path/to/file/on/remote/host
```

Your error is that there is no directory /user/pradeep on 172.100.102.187 or that user has no right to see it ^^

Try ssh user@172.100.102.187 and cd /user/pradeep you should get the same error.

my2c

Answer (score 0):

For file-- scp filename(with path) root@ip address or hostname:/root/path of the file

For directory--scp -r directory name(with path) root@ip address or hostname:/root/Directory path